# Set of subspaces of vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Let $V$ be a (real) vector space. Consider the set $\mathscr{V}$ consisting of all subspaces of $V .$ Equipping $\mathscr{V}$ with the addition of subspaces, is it possible to define a notion of scalar multiplication on $\mathscr{V}$ so that it becomes a vector space?

This seems very interesting question
Set of All subspaces of vector space V form vector space or not ?
As we know sum will be easy to check since if W and Z are subspaces of V then W + Z is also subspace. But what about scalar multiplication.

Comment: Before you even talk about scalar multiplication, you need to make sure your addition operation on $\scr V$ is a group operation. It has an identity element, the zero subspace, but it does not have additive inverses.

Comment: As $U+U=U$ for all $U\in\mathcal{V}$, it's nowhere near even being an additive group.

Answer (score 3):

No. $M+N=M+W$ does not imply  $N=W$ so you don't even have to consider scalar multilication.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more ? Why it does not have additive inverse.

Comment: @mathsstudent For a simple example take three lines through the origin with different slopes in $\mathbb R^{2}$.

Comment: but looking at question they said equipping with addition of subspace what does that mean ?

Comment: @mathsstudent Addition of subspaces is defined by $M+ N=\{x+y: x \in M, y \in N\}$.